# Adding grails 3 plugin intro grails 2 project

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

Is there any posibility to make it work a plugin created using grails 3 as a dependency of a grails 2 project? Both projects use the same groovy version.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any posibility to make it work a plugin created using grails
>   3 as a dependency of a grails 2 project?

Not really.  We re-wrote the plugin system in Grails 3 such that Grails 3 plugins are not compatible with Grails 2 and vice-versa.

That said, Grails 3 plugins are just .jar files.  You could have a Grails 2 application which depends on a Grails 3 plugin (just express the dependency like a normal library dependency, not a plugin dependency) and then whatever classes are in the Grails 3 plugin jar will be available in the Grails 2 app, but you won't have any of the plugin specific behavior imposed, you would just have access to the classes in the jar.  Depending on the particulars, that might or might not be helpful.

For the most part the answer to your question is "no".

> Both projects use the same groovy version.

That doesn't sound right.  I think the latest version of Grails 2 supports an earlier version of Groovy than the earliest version of Grails 3.

Comment: Thank you so much for you reply. Ok, so do we have any possibility to add the grails 3 project as a dependency of the grails 2 without a jar or via inplace-plugin? I mean... having the grails 3 project as a dependency and having it in the same workspace without generating a jar each time we change some code in the grails 3 project?

Comment: @mannuk I suppose the answer to both questions is "yes", but there would be no good reason to do that.  You won't be consuming it as a plugin, you will just have access to the classes in the .jar.  Because of that, there is no reason to configure it as a plugin but instead I would just treat it as a plain ol' Groovy/Java library.

Comment: Thank you so much!